# Mac Bash shell how to display editor in separate Window

Tags: bash, macos, editor, background-process, display

I would like to open an editor in a separate window from my terminal (MacOS bash shell).
When I run for example `vi &` or `emacs &` the process starts but no window pops up.
Could you please tell me how to display the editor (probably a config variable to set) ?

Thank you !

Comment: Since it sounds like you want to open an editor without losing your current shell command line, you might be interested in [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

You can start vi in a separate window with :

```
open -a Terminal /usr/bin/vi
```